# How to check if proxy is used in HttpClient and how to turn the proxy off?

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient

My java desktop application uses httpclient as REST client. The communication (simple GET operations) is very slow. I think, the operating system (Windows 7) proxy settings are used, although the particular destination IP-address is excluded from the proxy settings. Somewhere must be the bottleneck.

Is there a way to check if httpclient uses a proxy? If it so, how can I turn the proxy off (in httpclient).

I already have tried to work with -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false and so on; no effect.

Comment: You can use fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) to inspect the http calls that are sent to the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) to inspect http requests.  Looking at the request you should be able to determine whether or not a proxy is being used.